# Is it normal I get 0 size tempfile in my controller if I instantiate Rack::Test::UploadedFile once and reuse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

While upgrading my app from Rails 4.2.10 to 5.2.1 I noticed what seems a strange behavior to me. I have a single `fixture_file_upload` call in my `setup do` of `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` subclass. I try to upload a file before authentication (shall fail) and after (shall pass). Apparently on the first attempt I ignored the tempfile on controller side, but I noticed that on the second attempt the tempfile size is zero!

```
rails new zzz-5.2.1 --skip-yarn -G -M -C -S -J
rails generate scaffold blah file:binary --no-stylesheets --no-helper --no-jbuilder --no-javascript
bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

Now controller code for create

```
...
  # POST /blahs
  # POST /blahs.json
  def create
    f = blah_params[:file]
    puts "*** #{f.size} ***\n" # <-- to peek on size
    @blah = Blah.new(blah_params)
...
```

and test

```
  setup do
    @blah = blahs(:one)
    @file = fixture_file_upload('test/fixtures/blahs.yml')
  end
...
  test "should create blah" do
    assert_difference('Blah.count', 2) do
      post blahs_url, params: { blah: { file: @file } }
      post blahs_url, params: { blah: { file: @file } } # <- reuse @file
    end

    assert_redirected_to blah_url(Blah.last)
  end
```

And that is what I get after `bundle exec rake test`

```
C:\dev\ruby\zzz-5.2.1>bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 11056

# Running:

....*** 128 ***
*** 0 ***
...

Finished in 1.576030s, 4.4415 runs/s, 5.7106 assertions/s.
7 runs, 9 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Notice that the size is 0 for the second call. Am I missing something or shall I report a regression?

Comment: I noticed a similar thing I believe. When I instantiate a `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` in integration spec and check params in controller I see that it actually correctly sets `Content-Type` but calling `tempfile.size` returns 0. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯